# Why It requires the default constructor instead of using my factory method directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using **Visual Studio 2017** I have an **ASP.NET Core** MVC application. I registered the necessary method of my factory, because in the model each instance of each my class can be created only through the factory:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ITechnicalTask>(_ =>
        // It returns ITechnicalTask instance
        ModelFactory.Current.CreateTechnicalTaskTemplate(
            "Template Name"));

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

}
```

My controller has such methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateTemplate() => View();

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateTemplate(ITechnicalTask item)
{    
    repo.Templates.Add(item);
    return View("TemplatesList");
}
```

This is my form:

```
<form asp-action="CreateTemplate" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TemplateName">Template name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="TemplateName" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Accept
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I get exception when I press `Accept` button:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type
>   'PikProject.RobotIRA.ITechnicalTask'. Model bound complex types must
>   not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless
>   constructor.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)

Why It requires the default constructor? Why it is not enough to use my factory method?

**UPD**

My *business-model* is located in other project. All its classes are `internal`. Only interfaces and couple classes are `public`. Also it defines *the factory* interface for creating of necessary instances of the interfaces:

```
public interface IModelFactory {

    IEmployee CreateEmployee(string name,
        string middleName, string surname,
        string post);

    IAddress CreateAddress(string country, string region,
            string town, string street, string hoseNumber = "",
            string notes = "");

    IApproval CreateApproval(IEmployee employee,
        DateTime? datetime = null);

    IApprovalCollection CreateApprovalCollection();

    IRequirementsCollection CreateRequirementsCollection();

    IRequirement CreateRequirement(RequirementTypes type);

    ITechnicalTask CreateTechnicalTaskTemplate(string name);

    ITechnicalTask CreateTechnicalTaskDocument(
        string templateName);

    ITechnicalTaskCollection CreateTechnicalTaskCollection();

    IRepository CreateRepository();
}
```

The current factory is always accessible through the `ModelFactory.Current` property of that assembly. So, no classes or constructors which are accessible in my `ASP.NET Core MVC` project.

Comment: That is not how the framework works. You could create a custom model binder and apply your factory method functionality there.

Comment: I don't understand you.

Comment: Give Documentation a read first next time, reference [How model binding works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#how-model-binding-works)

Comment: @AndreyBushman: You'd need to create your custom model binder iirc, if you want your models to be resolved via DI before they are being binded. iirc when using `[FromService]` attribute to resolve a type it won't populated by the model binder. Also seems you are having external dependencies in your model, you should avoid that. Only services should have dependencies in it's constructor, but not models

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) and [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#how-model-binding-works). There is a big difference. Consider doing the following instead.

Register `IModelFactory` as a service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IModelFactory>(ModelFactory.Current);

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Now in your controller, use `FromServices` to get the instance and from the post take the value needed to create your model using `FromForm`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateTemplate([FromForm] string name, 
                                    [FromServices] IModelFactory factory)
{
    var item = factory.CreateTechnicalTaskTemplate(name);
    repo.Templates.Add(item);
    return View(nameof(TemplatesList));
}
```

You're factory should be treated as a service. Model binding expects a POCO, not an interface.

Comment: I added the **UPD** section for clarity.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works fine. Also the `nameof(TemplatesList)` is very usefull construction.