# ASP.NET CORE 2: Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to use IOptions to get configuration via POCO but it throws the error message 'Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor'

*DatabaseSettings.cs*

```
public class DatabaseSettings
    {
        public string MongoDBServer { get; set; }
    }
```

*appsettings.json*

```
"DatabaseSettings": {
    "MongoDBServer": "localhost"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddMvc();
      services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
}
```

*Controller*

```
public IActionResult Create(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> options)
{
  string test = options.Value.MongoDBServer;
  return View();
}
```

I don't know how to handle it. Do you have an advise for me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to inject the options into the constructor, not into your action method.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632346/why-it-requires-the-default-constructor-instead-of-using-my-factory-method-direc) answer helpful.

Please try to add [FromServices] to the controller action:

```
public IActionResult Create([FromServices] IOptions<DatabaseSettings> options)
```